# Setting use_sim_time globally across all ROS2 nodes

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to set the `use_sim_time` ROS2 parameter across all nodes?

I want all my nodes to `use_sim_time` globally by default since most of my work is in simulation.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/386817/setting-use_sim_time-globally-across-all-ros2-nodes/) by [Blake McHale](https://answers.ros.org/users/61567/blake-mchale/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2021-09-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you can use `SetParameter` in this case.

- https://github.com/tier4/AutowareArchitectureProposal_launcher/blob/8cd04aabd4f07d867bd9f3d77241550a5b9263ab/autoware_launch/launch/logging_simulator.launch.xml#L25
- https://github.com/tier4/AutowareArchitectureProposal.iv/blob/6adeec28d85dd41beaeb5a398ace899573bfda2a/common/util/autoware_global_parameter_loader/launch/global_params.launch.py#L27

---

Originally posted by [Kenji Miyake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44068/kenji-miyake/) with karma: 307 on 2021-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Blake McHale](https://answers.ros.org/users/61567/blake-mchale/) on 2021-09-22**:
Thanks! I ended up using `SetParameter` since I only needed to change one parameter across all nodes. I did not look into `RewrittenYaml`.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could be interested in the RewrittenYaml function from navigation2.
Check this conversation out to learn more about it: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/issues/2117

Cheers

---

Originally posted by [flo](https://answers.ros.org/users/55147/flo/) with karma: 111 on 2021-09-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1